# Windows ssh - How to keep proccess running after Disconnect

Tags: ssh, minecraft, openssh

I want to start a java Process(Minecraft Server) over SSH(PHP Script). And on disconnect it should not be closed.

I am using Bitvise SSH Server for Windows and 64 Bit Java. 
I can start the server but if I disconnect from the ssh server then the java Process(Minecraft server) stops.
I tried with PUTTY but same Problem.

Is there a command for cmd, like screen for Linux, which puts a process in the background?

Thanks.

Comment: Use some tools like `tmux` or `screen`.

Comment: But on windows with cmd there is no linux command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using OpenSSH server for windows.
Managed to get it working using this Power shell command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList C:\path\your-command.exe
```

Comment: This only works for admin users. Non-admin users will get "access denied" because WMI requires interactive logon but ssh is network logon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question on Super User: [Windows - Run process on background after closing cmd](https://superuser.com/q/1069972/688600)

So what you will do is:

```
start javaw.exe <arguments>
```

This will keep the process running after you disconnect from SSH, which will close the CMD session you issued the command.

Comment: That appears to only work if (and as long as) the user is logged into a Windows desktop session.  For me, at least, signing out of Windows also terminates the processes that were opened in the ssh session (from a remote computer).

However, the "powershell Invoke-WmiMethod" answer above does seem to keep the process running even after the user has logged out of Windows (and ssh).

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Coreutils/cygwin installed then you can run `start nohup your-command > logfile.txt` and it should remain running when you exit the ssh session. This works with the OpenSSH server that comes with Windows 10.